# nodejs + express server side precompiling per request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

When using handlebars with express js on the server side, and more specifically with express-handlebars module, does res.render part, compile, renders and send the final html to the client?. Is there a pre compilation step required, the rendering is happening on the server?

Thanks,

A

Comment: what do you mean by `compile` in this case? res.render takes your data, inserts it into the template, and sends html to the client.

Comment: @KevinB by compiling i mean the transformation of the .handlebars file to js functions. That is the concept at least when using client side templating, you precompile them before sending them in the browser. I was wondering if this concept exists in the server as well.

Comment: the rendering (converting template+data to html) is happening on the server, if that's what you're asking.. still a bit unclear.

Comment: What I mean is : whether the rendering (converting template+data to html) involves converting the template in js (http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) first. I assume that the rendering engine handles this on the background, but I was wondering if there was a way to optimise this process. Sorry if I am totally off here, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I think that's only useful if you're using handlebars on the client side. If you're doing the rendering server-side, i don't think there will be much savings.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, my motivation was basically understanding the caching mechanism behind the module.  How it caches the templates and if there is a way to improve this.

Comment: `express-handlebars.js` uses caching so there is *compilation to functions* when you start your app. When you call res.render it will spit out the html and send it to client.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you either set your views to cache:

```
app.set('view cache', true);
```

Or just run your app in production mode properly:

```
NODE_ENV=production node index.js
```

No other caching mechanisms are needed **on the server**.